# stop a list from going off the bottom of the page

Tags: php, file, list, directory

I have a php foreach script that will go through all files in a directory and list them out, with an icon for folders, and an icon for files.

As the list just goes until it has checked all files and folders, it just goes off the bottom of the page.

Just curious as to what people think the easiest way would be, to get the below code to break onto another column once it hits the bottom of the page?

```
foreach (glob("$dir/*") as $filename) {
    //Set the full path and filename
    $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
    //Set the filename to display
    $itemname = $path_parts['basename'];
    //Remove bullet points from the list
    echo "<ul style='list-style:none'>";
    //If it is a directory, list it. Else do nothing
    if(is_dir($filename)) {
        //Link points back to lister, with new directory
        echo "<li><a href='list.php?dir=".$filename."' style='font-size:18px;'>
        <img src='/site/images/files/folder.png' height='32px' width='32px' border='0' />&nbsp;".$itemname."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Appreciate any advice people can offer

Eds

Comment: What do you mean by the bottom of the page? Are you saying that you don't want a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: As there is many of the screen resolutions (thus different display heights) I would recommend breaking the list into columns using JavaScript (easily achieved with jQuery)...

Comment: What you will do when horizontal scrollbar appears?

Comment: Why is it an issue for it scroll vertically? Would having the page automatically scroll as it outputs help?

Comment: I would like to avoid the horizontal scroll bar, so if after spreading the list across the page I have to have a vertical scroll bar instead, then thats fine. The reason I want to avoid scrolling where possible, is it looks silly to have a reallly long list using almost none of the width of the page, and going quite a way down and having to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goal, all depends on how you want to present the information: ordered, unordered, columns organized by height, columns organized by width, etc..

So, for starting point, you can do something along this lines:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" style="font-size:18px;">
                <img src="path_to_image.png" height="32px" width="32px"> Name
            </a>
        </li>
        ...
        <li>
            <a href="#" style="font-size:18px;">
                <img src="path_to_image.png" height="32px" width="32px"> Name
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* what you need to pay attention to */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 330px;
}
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 0;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

/* some styles to links */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

/* clear float */
br {
  clear: left;
}
```

What this does is set a fixed width to the `LI` element, and floating it to the left, so as long as they fit side by side, the columns keep piling up.

`UL` width limits the number of columns that you desire!

See the Fiddle [example here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/FwtdJ/)

[image]

---

**Now, if you intend to prevent the vertical scrolling from ever appearing**, you need to go with an extra css line:

CSS

```
ul {
    height: 100px;
}
```

What this does is to limit the height of the list wrap, thus forcing the items to keep on going to the left.
Take not that you should remove the `width` from that `UL` to allow the columns to keep piling up to the left.

See the [Fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/FwtdJ/7/)

[image]

Comment: this is great, should do the job beautifully. thanks very much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Tick the answer to close this topic if this solves your issue!

Comment: hi, hopefully you can help tweak this slightly. I have found that in IE9, when the name of the list item is too wide, and breaks down a line, it causes a list item to be pushed one space to the right. Please see my adjusted fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FwtdJ/12/

Comment: Sorry, i'm an idiot. I just added a height css line sufficient to accommodate for the line break and it works fine. Thanks again